# Self-Hosting FontAwesome on S3

Tags: css, amazon-s3, less, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I'm trying to self-host FontAwesome (using LESS), but I'd like to serve up the css and webfonts directories from our S3 cloud instead of from the site, for performance reasons.  Is this possible?  I haven't been successful yet since the css looks for the webfonts directory in a relative location.

Can I create a "Kit" like FontAwesome does with their own CDN?  We prefer not to use the FontAwesome CDN for various customization and security reasons.

Comment: only host your update / customization , CDN files are mostly already loaded once a visitors shows up.